# External HDD inaccessible after formatting ext4+LUKS

Tags: linux, backup, external-hard-drive, arch-linux

In an attempt to establish a backup of my Arch Linux installation, I reformatted my My Passport Ultra 1 TB Drive. It was previously used on Windows, so I think the file system was NTFS (although I'm not sure).

I reformatted the drive as ext4+LUKS from gnome's GUI file browser. Before formatting, the drive was viewable from Files/Dolphin but now it doesn't show up in the file browsers at all. I want to use Areca backup's GUI but cannot access the drive.

I can still see the drive from Gnome's Drives utility, and can successfully unlock it from there with the password I set when formatting. Attempting to format it again generates the error

```
Error wiping device: Command-line `wipefs -a "/dev/sdb1"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: wipefs: error: /dev/sdb1: probing initialization failed: Device or resource busy
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

`$ fdisk -l` gives the below output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000170586112 bytes, 1953458176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf04b09ff

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 1953458175 1953456128 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

`$ partprobe -s /dev/sdb1`:

```
Error: Partition(s) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64 on /dev/sdb1 have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now before making further changes.
```

(I have just rebooted but the above message is the same).

Unsure how to proceed from here.

TYIA

Comment: Are all of these messages coming from a terminal or GParted? I had an error where I couldn't open a 1TB LUKS/ext4 drive because it wasn't properly mounting and it often reported as busy. Do you have a mount point with proper arguments setup in fstab? Also, are you successful at opening and working with other encrypted drives on the distro?

Answer (score 0):

The Disks/udisks error means the device is currently *in use* – e.g. it has been already unlocked (re-lock or `cryptsetup close` it) or mounted (unmount it).

Use `lsblk`, `findmnt`, and `dmsetup ls` to check what may be using it.

The partprobe message means you're using partprobe wrong. It doesn't work with individual partitions – it expects to be given a whole *disk* from which it'll read the partition table itself. The way you're using it now, it tries to interpret the LUKS header as a partition table, receiving garbage.

Use `partprobe /dev/sda` instead.